# Using values from the entry event in an Update Contact activity in Journey Builder

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

We use the `Update Contact` Activity in Journey Builder to store some behavioural informations in a log Data Extension of ours. We are injecting contacts into the journey from a DE. In the Update Contact Activity, we declare the following :

```
Subscriber Key = {{Event.DEkey.Contact Key}}
Information = Static Data
```

where Contact Key is a dynamic field value taken from the input entry. DEKey is retrieved by API its value is correct in our journey.

However, our log DE is not populated, even though the journey canvas shoes some contacts crossed the activity.

Any clue what could be wrong here ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, your input field has a space, so it needs to be enclosed inside parenthesis. Try :

```
Subscriber Key = {{Event.DEkey."Contact Key"}}
```

This should work.

You can reference Journey Datas, or Contact Datas this way, which makes this activity much more useful. See [here for details](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000357997&type=1).

Also, this activity can be used as a logging feature, since it updates only existing records, but add new ones if no matching entry is found. It should be renamed "Upsert" Activity.